# how to upgrade node v0.35.1 to 10.19.0

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

```
Present Version    
 wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.1/install.sh | bash
```

now I use Node.js in version 0.35.1, how to upgrade 10.19.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install Node.js v10.19.0 using nvm, execute the following command:

```
nvm install 10.19.0
```

To switch to the newly installed version, execute the following command:

```
nvm use 10.19.0
```